# The acc of model is too low when I using tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tflearn

There is a keras code which from gtihub
https://github.com/uci-cbcl/DanQ/blob/master/DanQ_train.py
The acc of it is nearly 0.97.

[image]

I want to code by tflearn.
but the acc is only about 0.1.

[image]

The model is simplicity and it's same as the keras.
I research it for three days,but I don't what's wrong.
Here is my code:

```py
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
from scipy.io import loadmat as load
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected, flatten,reshape
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_1d, max_pool_1d
from tflearn.layers.recurrent import bidirectional_rnn,BasicLSTMCell,lstm,gru
from tflearn.layers.normalization import batch_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tflearn.optimizers
import numpy as np
# Data loading and preprocessing
train = load('train.mat')
X=train['trainxdata']
Y=train['traindata']

# Building convolutional network
X=np.transpose(X,axes=[0,2,1])
network = input_data(shape=[None, 1000, 4], name='input')
network=conv_1d(network,32,26,padding='valid',activation='relu',regularizer='L2')
network = max_pool_1d(network,kernel_size=13,strides=13)
batch_normalization(network)
network = dropout(network, 0.2)
network = flatten(network)
network = fully_connected(network, 925, activation='relu')
network = fully_connected(network, 919, activation='sigmoid')
network = regression(network, optimizer='Adam', learning_rate=0.01,loss='binary_crossentropy', name='target')
# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
       validation_set=0.1, snapshot_step=60, show_metric=True, run_id='DanQ')}
```

I am a foreign student，and I am sorry that my English is poor.
This is my first using Stackoverflow.
Thanks for asking my question!

Comment: Your results from `keras` are shown after putting 14K example to train algorithm. In `tf` - after 1.2K - maybe you should wait a little bit longer?

Comment: `dropout(network, 0.2)` means there is only a 20% chance to keep each neuron, which seems very low to me.

Comment: The number of example and the dropout are unifluence to the acc,I have to change them but unuse.I think the problem it's the loss don't change,it always be 0.68327 after 1000 examples.

Comment: [link](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c0fqWI)Here is the trainmat  from the original resources which have 3.6G,The mini-trainmat is correct,I had try it by keras code then got right result.